# Advanced MySQL: Display only items that have not been updated in 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to display only listings that have not been updated in the last thirty days.

This query works fine except for it is obviously missing the thirty day update requirement:

```
$Listings = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings, ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings_to_users WHERE ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings_to_users.ID = ".$Userprofile->ID." AND ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_visibility = 1 AND ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_id = ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings_to_users.listing_id");
```

I have tried this, but to no avail:

```
$Listings = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings, ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings_to_users WHERE ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings_to_users.ID = ".$Userprofile->ID." AND ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_visibility = 1 AND ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_id = ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings_to_users.listing_id AND ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated < unix_timestamp(now() - interval 30 day");
```

In case you need the following information, I am storing the date in the database with the following timestamp format: 2011-02-12 22:23:01. I must be missing something relatively simple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You really should rethink the way you construct your queries. It is impossible to read them like this. This is a typical source of bugs in the end!

Comment: The second query can't even work, it's missing a right brace at the end. Please provide the definition of the table, is the date an actual TIMESTAMP or a VARCHAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
$Listings = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings, ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings_to_users WHERE ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings_to_users.ID = ".$Userprofile->ID." AND ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_visibility = 1 AND ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_id = ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings_to_users.listing_id AND date_format(".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings.listing_last_updated,'%Y%m%d')<date_format(adddate(now(),interval -30 day),'%Y%m%d')");
```